# Getting duplicate session id for multiple user

Tags: java, spring, websphere-portal, vaadin6

i am working on multi user web application which has technology stack like  vaadin 6.7, web sphere portal server 8 and springs.

When multiple user login (different machines with different login )  at the same time.I noticed all the user generating the same http session id (httpservletrequest.getSession()) for all the three request because of which session parameter got replaced.
i did some research and find out vaadin 6 has some problem related to providing single instance of vaddinApplication instead of providing the new instance for new user but to tackle this problem. We also implement thread local to tackle this problem. 
Can any one provide me a theory why because of singleton instance of vaadinApplication i am getting the same session.
May be old session replaced with the new one but i am not sure regarding this theory.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of vaadin 6.7 has the application class which dosen't give the new instance of application for the new user. So, i have to use thread local for the new instance of application. Previously thread local is used but only for one functionality.I read this problem is solved in vaadin 7  :)